# python regex match only last occurrence

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'm experiencing some problems implementing a regular expression for a repeating string pattern.

```
>>> re.findall('(\(\w+,\d+\)(?:,)?)+', '(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)')
['(e,f)']
```

I would like ro get the other items as well

Help would be really appriciated

Comment: Really, `f` was matched by `\d`? I rather doubt that. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `+`; your pattern matches **all** occurrences, but the group can only capture one occurrence, you cannot repeat a capturing group that way:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('(\(\w+,\w+\),?)+', '(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)')
['(e,f)']
>>> re.findall('\(\w+,\w+\),?', '(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)')
['(a,b),', '(c,d),', '(e,f)']
```

where I replaced the `\d` with `\w` to demonstrate, and removed the redundant non-capturing group around the comma. The outermost capturing group is also redundant; without it, `re.findall()` returns the whole matched expression.